# Selenium and SSL Unicode error

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, unicode

I'm new to Selenium and Python and am trying to launch a single webpage through Firefox and save the output of that one page. The SSL site is not self-signed and this script runs fine on sites that are not SSL. The Firefox profile is configured with a socks5 proxy.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("./MyProfile")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://www.sslexample.com/')
html = driver.page_source

f = open("test.html", "wt")
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\PythonPrograms\st01.py", line 16, in <module>
    f.write(html)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0100' in position 1842: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried playing with encoding and things, but I'm not getting anywhere. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `codecs` when writing `UTF-8` to a file.

```
import os
import codecs
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("./MyProfile")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://www.sslexample.com/')
html = driver.page_source

with codecs.open('test.html', 'w', 'utf-8') as file_object:
    file_object.write(html)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I spent two days trying to figure this out so thanks for the help!